# Execution of exe files one completion then execute other

Tags: batch-file, dos, exe

I have one batch script inside I am calling .exe file and after complete execution of one exe file I want second file will execute, how to do it ? means I was got a hint to catch system.exit the output, but output whatever if it will give me echo..please press enter to exit then I want to catch it in that varible and proceed to next exe file otherwise not, but how to set this environment varible and from where it will read 0 or 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start /wait notepad.exe
if not %errorlevel%==0 exit
start /wait calc.exe
```

Note, that notepad.exe will only return "success" ("0") - so this is a bad example to demonstrate.

Comment: if say here notepad.exe have error then calc.exe should not get executed..how to check it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
start C:\yourdir\filename.exe
```

or if the other file is in the same dir put

```
start filename.exe
```